# Help identifying light bulb

Tags: light-bulb

[image][image]It goes in the lighting above my kitchen island but says nothing on the bulb so I am unable to identify the type of bulb

Comment: If there is a big box store nearby, take the bulb in and peruse the aisle with light bulbs...

Answer (score 1):

My guess is an MR16 GU5.3. But there are a lot of varieties of bi-pin bulb types, as explained [in this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bi-pin_lamp_base). Basically you need to look at multiple dimensions - size and shape of pins, size of bulb, etc. and also at the voltage - there are 12V (need a power pack somewhere) and 120V (line voltage) bulbs, though my hunch here is 12V.

If you can find *any* identifying codes on the bulb that would help. If not, you should be able to figure out the voltage with a multimeter or by finding any power pack/adapter if there is one.

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be either a GU4 or a GU5.3 base, both of which typically operate on 12v.  To be certain, you'll want to measure the voltage at the socket with a multimeter, and make sure it's 12VDC, and measure the distance between the pins - GU4 is 4mm spacing (on center), and GU5.3 is 5.3mm spacing.